# esi tag not working on laravel application

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, varnish, varnish-vcl

Hi I have the following issue. I have a website running laravel 5.1, to make the website available for many users and to have a faster load time I have made use of Varnish4. My varnish vlc file is as follows.

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.    
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 1m;
    return(deliver);
}
```

As you can see I enable esi processign for all requests(not the best practice but I'm trying to make things work), and remove all cookies in the vcl_recv subroutine.

Now, I have a blade template with an esi:include block as follows:

```
<esi:remove>
    NO ESI SUPPORT
    <script>window.load_hot = true;</script>
</esi:remove>
<!--esi
    <p>The full text of the license: 
         <esi:include src="http://localhost/date.php" />
    </p>
-->
```

The route on the esi include tag works OK and returns the expected output.
The Varnish system parses the ESI block as expected, because the fallback(show NO ESI SUPPORT) message is not displayed.

So, what can be going bad on this code?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

For some reason this:

```
<esi:remove>
    NO ESI SUPPORT
    <script>window.load_hot = true;</script>
</esi:remove>
<!--esi
    <p>The full text of the license: 
         <esi:include src="http://localhost/date.php" />
    </p>
-->
```

was not working due to the  tag.

After removing the tag like this:

```
<esi:remove>
    NO ESI SUPPORT
    <script>window.load_hot = true;</script>
</esi:remove>

<p>The full text of the license: 
         <esi:include src="http://localhost/date.php" />
</p>
```

The esi inclusion begun to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The esi:include tag only takes a path and not a complete URL with protocol and hostname etc., e.g.

```
<esi:include src="/cgi-bin/date.cgi"/>
```

See: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/esi.html

Comment: Sorry to say that this was not the problem. Check my answer which has an absolute url on the esi:include tag